# Javascript functions in a webpage

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to list all the functions referenced by a webpage and the .js file(s) that define them?

Comment: And here comes the trailing question mark missing from the end of your sentence: "?"

Comment: @H2CO3 added them, waiting for peer review...

Comment: @H2CO3 You see, omitting a character can seem like a tiny little thing, but considering he's asked 225 questions that does add up... On the other hand, you could just edit the question.

Comment: @H2CO3 But if you end the sentence there you'll be ending in a superfluous preposition!

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs Koszi szepen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best thing for this job would be to use a development console such as Chrome's developer tools or Firebug. This will allow you to 'record' a webpage and see all of its JavaScript executions and where they originated.